# FullCalendar display only an event in End Date instead of a line starting in Start Date and ending in End Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar.js on Ruby on Rails and im having problems to customize it.
I want to display only the Events in its end date, instead of a line starting in the Start Date and ending in End Date.
I have this code:

the json

```
json.array!(@projects) do |project|
  json.extract! project, :id
  json.title project.name
  json.start project.start_date
  json.end project.end_date
  json.url project_url(project)
```

and this is what i get in the view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGWaC.jpg

I dont want the line in every day a Project is being done, i only want to know in the callendar when a Project is ending (the ones with only one day are Projects without end_date, but i want something like that).

Comment: maybe your project start date value is not what you expect it to be, print that on console, and you may want to post that instead of the json you posted.

Comment: "id": {
"$oid": "5565e2656162630b159d0200"
},
"title": "Evolui",
"start": "2015-01-23",
"end": "2015-06-03",
"url": "http://localhost:9000/projects/5565e2656162630b159d0200"

this is a complete json with start/end date it starts the line in 2015-01-23 and ends at 2015-06-03 i want it to display only a line in 2015-06-03

Comment: try `json.start project.end_date` and remove `json.end ....` line. I am not sure I understood correctly though

Comment: when i got that problem i tried that and it displays nothing in the calendar...

Answer (score 0):

Now it works, it wasnt working because sometimes there is no Project.end_date and the FullCalendar needs a start date, i changed the query just to get the Projects where end_date is present